# Created function to print username and timestamp to single cell like "A1"

Tags: excel, vba

I have made an function in VBA macro to print only the username and timestamp value to particular cell which I will pass in argument at time of calling  but when I am calling it will give me an error

> "Type mismatch" or "expected="

Calling an function `AddTimeStamp("A1",1)` or `AddTimeStamp(A1,1)`

code is

```
Public Function AddTimeStamp(myRange As Range, tempValue As Integer) 

    If tempValue = 1 Then
    Range(myRange).Value = "User: " & Application.UserName & " and Timestamp: " & Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM") '"m.d.yy h:mm AM/PM"

    Else
    Range(myRange).Value = "Insert name of responder and timestamp of response."

    End If


End Function
```

Could you please help me how to call this function or some error in my function .please guide me i am new to VBA MAcro

Comment: ```"A1"``` is a string, ```A1``` is a variable you want ```Range("A1")```.

Comment: Change `Range(myRange).Value` to `myRange.Value`.... and make this a `Sub` instead of a `Function`... and drop the parentheses when calling it.

Comment: Hi Warcupine i want to pass A1 cel value so i was bit confused how i need to pass it 
   AddTimeStamp("A1",1) or AddTimeStamp(A1,1)

Comment: Hi Bigben ,I have updated as you suggest but while calling an Sub it will give me error like when i am calling like   Call AddTimestamp(A1,1)  Error-ByRef argument type mismatch and Call AddTimeStamp("A1",1)   Error- Type Mismatch. Please suggest

Comment: Hi Bigben  i got the solution i need to call like Call AddTimeStamp(Range("A1"), 1) and in my Sub need to add "ByRef" for my range argument thanks you very much .thanks